# API warning when trying to create a flutter appbundle

Tags: firebase, admob, flutter-dependencies

When I try to create an appbundle flutter it shows me a note from the firebase admob api, but it finishes creating the apk. Should I worry about the warning?

> Note: C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Comment: I got the same and raised the issue here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56234

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened with me when I was using wrong "adUnitId", I was using the application ID instead D).

Please make sure that you are using the correct adUnitId for your bannerAd or InterstitialAd.